# Download WMS tiles with R and use in tmap

Tags: r, wms

I have access to a password protected WMS service (https://wms.swisstopo.admin.ch/) and I would like to download tiles for a bounding box with R. Then I would like to use them as background for a map created with tmap. The layer name is `ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe-pk25.noscale`. I don't know where to give the authentication information.

I saw this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983053/extracting-data-from-a-wms-layer but using `sf::st_read()` gives the following error: `The file doesn't seem to exist`.

I would like to have the WMS data of this extent (CRS is CH1903+):

```
xmin       : 2581809 
xmax       : 2583643 
ymin       : 1181706 
ymax       : 1182825
```

Then, I would like to plot the map with `tmap::tm_rgb()` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tmap/versions/3.2/topics/tm_raster). How can I do this?

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://github.com/hypertidy/ceramic & https://github.com/MilesMcBain/slippymath

Comment: Thanks a lot, I could download the tiles with curl_download() after extracting the correct WMS URL with all parameters from QGIS.

Comment: @Mario, could you share your solution here?